# How to compile an application using gcc to convert float to int on ARM？

Tags: gcc, arm, int, cross-compiling

I want to compile an application which contains float functions and variables,but I just do not want to produce float instructions in the binary.Can     that be achieved by adding some flags in the cross compile tool chain gcc? 
 Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Can you clarify? Some instructions execute only on cores with FPU hardware. If that's what you want to avoid, you would compile and link with soft floating point library.

Answer (score 1):

gcc can handle float operations without using fpu instructions via `-mfloat-abi=soft`, see [gcc's arm options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html).

However be careful that if you handle floating point via libraries, you need to either link them in static, or your target needs to provide same ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cross-compiled the source code with the flag -mfloat-abi=soft as follows: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -mfloat-abi=soft -static XX.c . But,the compiler complained that "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error：unrecognized command line option ‘-mfloat-abi=soft’ ". Does that means the aarch64 cross-compiler not include the library which can convert float instructions to int instructions?

Comment: Why do you use 64 bit toolchain?